# Drawable gets stretched to fit the view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-drawable

I'm trying to set a Bitmap Drawable as the background like this, `root.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);`, I've set its bounds to be 1080 wide by 300 high, but it keeps stretching to fit the entire background. Is there any way to avoid this? This is how i created the `BitmapDrawable` `BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable= new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the default [`Gravity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html) of a `BitmapDrawable` is `FILL`. Try setting the `Gravity` to `CENTER`:

```
bitmapDrawable.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: Thanks! although i set it to Gravity.TOP instead. But I've an other question, if you have the time. If I have multiple BitmapDrawable and than put them in a LayerDrawable `LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(bitmapDrawables);`. They all get layered on top of each other. I'd like them to get added like a list, one after the other, below each other. How would i go about doing that?

Comment: @Axonshi123 As far as I know there is no [`Drawable`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) that will handle what you are asking. I think I have a solution for you, but it is a bit of code. So post this as a new question and link to it here, I'll post an answer.